# Running shortest path analysis for DEM-derived streams and pour points?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, dem, spatial-analyst, arc-hydro

I have a .shp for streams and another for pour points. Those features were extracted from a DEM by using the Hydrology package from the Spatial Analyst Tools of ArcGIS 10.

I want to know the distance between every pour point along the flow path network. What procedure should I use?

Comment: Have you considered trying the [**Utility Network Analyst**](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//002r00000037000000) toolbar?  It's interactive but for only four points may remain suitable - and useful to look at while you are developing your procedure.

Comment: An alternate vector processing tool is RivEX, you could vectorize the data and use the site linking tool. Have a look at this page: http://www.rivex.co.uk/html/network-site-tools.html

Answer (score 1):

[Cost Path](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//009z00000019000000.htm) tool can be used to derive the path of least resistance down a digital elevation model (DEM). Use the DEM for the Input cost distance raster and the output from the [Flow Direction tool](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//009z00000052000000.htm) for the Input cost raster

Comment: @PolyGeo , Geog thanks for your comments.

I am actually trying to obtain an "OD Cost Matrix" for using it as a spatial weighting matrix in a Spatial Autocorrelation Test.

I have too much nodes/streams to do a manual analysis for every possible origin-destination pair in the drainage network.

I was looking for an automatic process to compose the OD Cost Matrix. 

I already tried to apply the Network Analysis Extension on a network dataset, which was created by right clicking the DEM-derived streams.shp in the ArcCatalog. But that did not work =(